# How does Javascript’s Math.random() works behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, computer-science

I've always wondered how on earth does Javascript picks a random number and how can it possibly be random? Don’t computers just take in some input, swirl it around with some math, and then return it?

I'm **not** asking how to generate a random number with Math.random(), my question is: **What happens when you want to generate a ‘random’ number?** **How does that even work and what’s happening behind the scenes?** I understand it's a big topic to discuss but any links will be appreciated!

Comment: This is a very big topic and falls into the category "too broad". There are lots of mathematical theories behind the scene. Please google for "Pseudorandom number generator" to get an initial idea.

Comment: I disagree, since the question only is concerned about a well-defined set of environments.

Comment: Many things could happen. One factor that goes into randomness: is system current timestamp

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: Since this is on hold, I'll just leave here a link to the ECMAScript specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.random

Answer (score 1):

Some random number generator functions use some kind of system noise or entropy (eg: current timestamp) and apply some mathematical function to it to generate random numbers. They are "true" random numbers.

Some functions work by using a seed value and an algorithm to generate numbers that appear to be random, but that is in fact predictable. They are called "Pseudorandom" numbers.

You can read more here: https://www.howtogeek.com/183051/htg-explains-how-computers-generate-random-numbers/

Comment: Taking a timestamp and applying a mathematical function doesn't sound like a true random number generator...

Comment: @FelixKling insert von Neumann quote here.

Comment: The timestamp is precise up to 6-7 decimal places and is recorded with a keystroke on the keyboard (just an example). It's nearly impossible to predict this.